# Tabhost setup() not working

Tags: android, android-tabhost, fragment-tab-host

I follow the tutorial in android documentation how to use Tabhost within Fragment, But I'm getting always

```
The method setup(android.content.Context, android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager, int) in the type FragmentTabHost is not applicable for the arguments (android.content.Context, android.app.FragmentManager, int)
```

My setup command is like this:

```
mTabHost.setup( getActivity().getApplicationContext(), getChildFragmentManager(), R.layout.fragment_vc_view);
```

Answer (score 9):

Sounds like your class in which you call the setup method extends `android.app.Fragment` and not `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`.

Comment: so what I need to change?

Comment: Change import android.app.Fragment to import android.support.v4.app.Fragment